# Узнать в каком div элемент

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,подскажите,пожалуйста,у меня таблицы находятся в div.Мне нужно по щелчку на таблицу в alert вывести в каком id она находиться.

```
$("table").click(function(){alert(...)})
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: $("table").click(function(){alert($(this).parent();)})    оно?

Comment: @myvzar,мне выдает [object Object]

Comment: $("table").click(function(){alert($(this).parent().attr('id');)}) - айдишка дива...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если таблицы вложены непосредственно в дивы, то

```
$("table").click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbtj3s5b/6/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("table").click(function() {
  // Так мы ищем первый родительский div, у которого есть атрибут ID
  var parentDivId = $(this).closest('div[id]').attr('id');
  alert(parentDivId)
});
```

```css
table,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div + div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Я столбец 1 в таблице 1</td>
        <td>Я столбец 2 в таблице 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Я столбец 1 в таблице 2</td>
      <td>Я столбец 2 в таблице 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```